# How to use AudioRecorder in Android

Tags: android, audio-recording

Im creating an application in which I want to integrate the audio recording feature and the output file must me in the **.mp3** format.. Please provide me some good tutorial through from where I can learn..

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the simple code to do this.

```
    MediaRecorder mediarecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediarecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediarecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediarecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediarecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/myv.mp3");
    try {
        mediarecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediarecorder.start();
```

Comment: you are using 3gp as output format but you are saving the file with the .mp3 extention... how is that possible?

Comment: dear 3gp is multimedia format for 3gp mobile phones.

Comment: ok... and can you please tell me how can I restart the recording with the same code?

Comment: just put mediarecorder.start();
wherever you want to start on button or whatever, and declare MediaRecorder object global.

Comment: it's mediaRecorder not audioRecorder

Answer (score 1):

try the following too:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;

public class AudioRecorder {

    final MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    final String path;

    public AudioRecorder(String path) {
        this.path = sanitizePath(path);
    }

    private String sanitizePath(String path) {
        if (!path.startsWith("/")) {
            path = "/" + path;
        }
        if (!path.contains(".")) {
            path += ".3gp";
        }
        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + path;
    }

    public void start() throws IOException {
        String state = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (!state.equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            throw new IOException("SD Card is not mounted.  It is " + state + ".");
        }

        File directory = new File(path).getParentFile();
        if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
            throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
        }

        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(path);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    public void stop() throws IOException {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: just add extension in path like .mp3

Answer (score 0):

try this [Android Audio Record](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html) & [Audio Record using MediaRecord Android API Tutorial](http://www.benmccann.com/blog/android-audio-recording-tutorial/)